# Parsing URL query and appending it at end of the other URL

Tags: php, url

I am trying to grab the URL query of the URL which is in the browser's address bar, then append it at the end of the other URL and echo it to the browser.

So, if I visit my script at:

> http://script.com/script.php?a=x&b=z

and the other URL is:

> http://google.com/?c=v&d=u

then the browser will display:

> http://google.com?a=x&b=z&c=v&d=u

This code is quite slow. How can I improve this?

```
 function parse_me($from, &$to) {
    // $to = array();
    $from = urldecode($from);
    $from = urldecode($from);

    foreach (explode('&', $from) as $part) {
        $part = explode('=', $part);
        if ($key = array_shift($part)) {
            $to[$key] = implode('', $part);
        }
    }
    // print_r($to);
}

function add_qsrt_to_url($url) {
    $other_query_string = arrayGet($_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', '');

    $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
    $new_qs_parsed = array();

    if (isset($url_parsed['query'])) {
        // parse_str($url_parsed['query'], $new_qs_parsed);
        parse_me($url_parsed['query'], $new_qs_parsed);
    }
    $other_qs_parsed = array();

    // parse_str($other_query_string, $other_qs_parsed);
    parse_me($other_query_string, $other_qs_parsed);
    // print_r($other_qs_parsed);

    $final_query_string_array = array_merge($new_qs_parsed, $other_qs_parsed);
    // var_dump($final_query_string_array);
    $final_query_string = http_build_query($final_query_string_array);
    $new_url = $url_parsed['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parsed['host'];

    if (isset($url_parsed['path'])) {
        $new_url = $new_url . $url_parsed['path'];
    }

    if ($final_query_string) {
        $new_url = $new_url . '?' . $final_query_string;
    }

    return $new_url;
}

function arrayGet($array, $key, $default = NULL) {
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Comment: Are they typos or are you using spaces after every dollar sign for real?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you break '?a=x&b=y' into a hash with two keys? Why not just copy the query string as is without parsing it?

Comment: @BarryCarter, because I want to merge its URL query with the existing URL query with of the other URL.

Comment: Oh, OK. Suggest you give a second URL more like "google.com/?c=v&d=u" so we can see the merging.

Comment: @BarryCarter, good suggestion, updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it like this

```
function concatQueryVars($first, $second) {
    $url = strtok($first, '?');
    $first = parse_url($first, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $second = parse_url($second, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    return !empty($url) && 
           !empty($first) && 
           !empty($second) 
           ? $url . '?' . $first. '&' . $second : false;
}

echo concatQueryVars('http://example.com/?a=b', 'http://example.com/?c=d&e=f');
```

Result:

> http://example.com/?a=b&c=d&e=f

Comment: I was going to suggest replacing the '?' in the script URL with an '&', but that wouldn't work in all cases. Your solution is better.